# Moment.js (^2.29.4), isSameOrAfter() and isSameOrBefore()

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

i'm using the latest version of Moment.js (^2.29.4) so i can use its function including isSameOrAfter() and isSameOrBefore() but when i use it i got an error message says that isSameOrAfter and isSameOrBefore are not functions this If statement :

```
if (!( (storedStartDate.isSameOrAfter(moment(req.body.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))) && 
            (storedEndDate.isSameOrBefore(moment(req.body.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))){...}
```

here is the version in my package.json :
"moment": "^2.29.4",

and i properly imported moment in the file

Comment: well, what is `storedStartDate`? Probably not a `moment`

Comment: it's a constant that contains a moment object

Comment: Obviously not ... If it was, you would be able to call `isSameOrAfter` and `isSameOrBefore` on it ...

Comment: i'll check my code again and thank you.